# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find StyleMasterPage name

Tags: coding-style

I'm developing an app that processes files in ODS format.The code snippet is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Set the platform L&F.
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    display();
    //print();
}

private static void display() throws IOException {
    // Load the spreadsheet.
    final OpenDocument doc = new OpenDocument();

    doc.loadFrom("temperature3.ods");
    String styleName = "Calibri";
    StyleHeader header = new StyleHeader();
    header.setStyleDisplay("Testing");
    StyleMasterPage page = new StyleMasterPage();
    page.setStyleHeader(header);
    page.setStyleName(styleName);
    OfficeMasterStyles off = new OfficeMasterStyles();
    off.addMasterPage(off.getMasterPageFromStyleName(styleName));

        doc.setMasterStyles(off);

    // Show time !
    final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Viewer");
    DefaultDocumentPrinter printer = new DefaultDocumentPrinter();

    ODSViewerPanel viewerPanel = new ODSViewerPanel(doc, true);

    mainFrame.setContentPane(viewerPanel);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setLocation(10, 10);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

I intend loading the file into a jcomponent for easy manipulation but I'm having this error message in the netbeans console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find StyleMasterPage named:Calibri
at org.jopendocument.model.office.OfficeMasterStyles.getMasterPageFromStyleName(Unknown Source)
    at starzsmarine1.PrintSpreadSheet.display(PrintSpreadSheet.java:60)
    at starzsmarine1.PrintSpreadSheet.main(PrintSpreadSheet.java:45)
```

Is there an alternative API for this purpose?